# RTX Support for Blender 2.79b

Tags: rendering, gpu

I've recently purchased an NVIDIA RTX 2070 Super GPU as an upgrade to my AMD Radeon GPU(Yes, pity me.). But I was slightly heartbroken when I realized you can't use an RTX card with Blender 2.79b. Yes, I know you can use it in Blender 2.83, but that version ruined the UI, and my character rigs won't work. Anyone have an addon, fix, patch, or even a link to a sketchy website that'll give me the version of Blender I want if I give my credit card number into return? I mainly use the cycles render engine. I know it would be easy to update Blender and just get a new character rig, but I'd really like to stay with Blender 2.79.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to use RTX cards with 2.79 you can use one of the 'nightly' builds of 2.79 that came between the latest release of 2.79 and 2.8.

From the '[Previous Versions](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/)' page (found by clicking the 'Blender 2.7' link from [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/)):

> You can also download the [experimental nightly build from July 2019](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/latest/)
> which basically looks like 2.7 plus additional bug fixes and some new
> features that later became part of 2.80.

Following that link takes you to [here](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/latest/) which is where the downloads reside. This allows you to download 2.79.7, which is compatible with RTX cards.

**Note**: These versions of Blender are the portable versions which run from the folder they are extracted to instead of coming with an installer.