# How do I manually enable RTX GPU render in Blender version 2.69 and 2.67b (Cycles Render and Blender Render)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a custom file, and it ONLY works none other than blender version 2.69, and 2.67b. Can someone code it for me please?

Comment: I doubt that is possible. Also, to request paid or unpaid comissions use https://blenderartists.org/c/jobs/14

Comment: RTX is possible in [2.79.7](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/188141/rtx-support-for-blender-2-79b/188143#188143) but not earlier as far as I know.

Comment: ik, but I need someone to manually code me Blender with RTX GPU into those versions. You guys know anyone who makes Blender versions?

Comment: All you need to do is reverse what they did in duplicate.